# Is it possible to render Vega Lite charts as SVG?

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite

What is the proper way to render Vega Lite charts as SVG?

I've been trying to render Vega Lite as svg to provide nicer and sharper responsive charts, an option that I know is available off the bat for Vega.

This embed setup was tested after some research:

```
  vegaEmbed(chartDivId, chart, myTooltip).then( function(result) {
    var view = result.view;
    view.run();
    view.logLevel(vega.None);
    view.renderer('svg');//<-- render as SVG
  }).catch(console.error);
```

Which actually did convert my charts from pixel image to SVG (tested zooming in and they preserved resolution). However, they got misaligned (see images below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Vega Embed like you are, but it's part of the options:

```
vegaEmbed(chartDivId, chart, {renderer: 'svg'})
```

See https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options for details.

Comment: I've tried this suggestion and it resulted in the same misalignment in the axis as shown in images in my post.

Comment: You should update the question to reflect that. Or accept and open another question for your bee issue.

Comment: I tried this vegaEmbed after your suggestion. Suggested solution didn't work thus I can't accept it.